Help, btrfs not mounting, dev extent overlap with previous dev extent
One of my btrfs file system not mount at boot anmore.
dmesg:
BTRFS error (device dm-7): dev extent devid 3 physical offset 725923790848 overlap with previous dev extent end 725923856384
BTRFS error (device dm-7): failed to verify dev extents against chunks: -117
BTRFS error (device dm-7): open_ctree failed

$ sudo btrfs check /dev/mapper/Cry01
Opening filesystem to check...
Checking filesystem on /dev/mapper/Cry01
UUID: 41639c09-856d-4eca-ab66-67b6fe4a9b01
[1/7] checking root items
[2/7] checking extents
Device extent[3, 725923790848, 2228224] existed.
Device extent[3, 2231203659776, 2555904] existed.
Device extent[4, 2094877769728, 1966080] existed.
Device extent[4, 2251644010496, 2031616] existed.
Device extent[4, 2284862767104, 2162688] existed.
Device extent[3, 3958666690560, 2228224] existed.
Device extent[3, 3963405860864, 2293760] existed.
ERROR: dev extent devid 3 physical offset 725923790848 overlap with previous dev extent end 725923856384
ERROR: errors found in extent allocation tree or chunk allocation
[3/7] checking free space cache
[4/7] checking fs roots
...

What should I do to remount the file system?
The filesystem is a 6 drive btrfs array with raid5 data, raid1c4 metadata.

Sounds like a drive has died. BTW I do not see any mention of Ubuntu in the question.
